# Google calendar edit event - description not saved when edited by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write an Chrome extension to fill in the event description in Google Calendar - edit event window. But when I add text there using Jquery: $('textarea').val('test'); and save the event, the description is not saved. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: You should probably `trigger()` a `change` or `input` event for the textarea. Or switch to `$('textarea').focus(); document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'test')`

Comment: Yes that helps :) But when I put this code in an onBlur event of a different field, and press save, it gets excecuted but still not saved :(

Comment: Solved that by calling this every onKeyUp event :) Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to insert the text by JS, and focus the field:

```
        $("#myfield").keyup(function(e){
            //text changed, update description field
            text_tv = $(this).val();
            descr.val('');
            descr.focus(); 
            document.execCommand('insertText', false, convert_to_tv(text_tv));
            $(this).focus();
        });
```